# How to use array value for case switching (not array number)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, switch-statement

How do you use the VALUE of an array number as opposed to what number in the array it is for determining case? In my code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            switch (position[x])
            {
                case 0:
                    label1.Text = people[x];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    label2.Text = people[x];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label3.Text = people[x];
                    break;
            }
        }
```

When this is run, it uses the x in position[] as opposed to position[x]'s value for determining which case to use. For instance, when x is 0, but position[x]'s value is 1, it uses case 0. How do I get the value instead?

**EDIT:** My code was indeed the problem.... For some reason debugging early in the morning has the effect of creating false images... :P As an FYI, here was the correct code...

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            if (position[x] == 2)
            {
                position[x] = 0;
            }

            else
            position[x]++;

        }

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            int val = position[x];
            switch (val)
            {
                case 0:
                    label1.Text = people[x];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    label2.Text = people[x];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label3.Text = people[x];
                    break;
            }
```

In the upper first appearance of position[x], I instead had placed only x. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: what's the purpose of 'position' then?

Comment: Your code looks fine, are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Are you sure the values in position[] are as you expect them to be?

Comment: Agreed...this code works just fine for me.

Comment: Maybe you want to do people[position[x]]?

Comment: Please provide a small, complete example that we can compile that demonstrates the behaviour you find perplexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        int val = position[x];
        switch (val)
        {
            case 0:
                label1.Text = people[x];
                break;
            case 1:
                label2.Text = people[x];
                break;
            case 2:
                label3.Text = people[x];
                break;
        }
    }
```

Maybe something easier would be to say:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    Label label = MyForm.ActiveForm.Controls["label" + position[x]] as Label;
    if (label != null) label.Text = people[x];
}
```

Comment: The semantics of this are exactly the same as what the OP posted.